# Function not properly returning with a list

Tags: python, function

Working on this code. When the program runs, `print(random_generator)` doesn't actually print out the quote, it simply says `<function 40x....>` in the shell. Any tips as to why this is happening?

```
import time  
import random 
quotes= ["Life is too short, so savior every moment", 
"Here's to the crazy ones, the rebels, square pegs in round holes",       
"You miss all the shots you don't take"]



def random_generator():   #RandomQuoteGenerator
    return random.choice(quotes)

timeout = 1     #Timer 
first_time = time.time()
last_time = first_time
while(True):
    pass #do something here
    new_time = time.time()
    if  new_time - last_time > timeout:
        last_time = new_time
        print(random_generator) 
        print ("Its been %f seconds" % (new_time - first_time))  #TimeCheck
```

Comment: `print(random_generator())`. I suspect you need to actually call the function.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want to actually print the results of `random_generator` you need to actually call it.

You have:

```
print(random_generator)
```

You probably wanted:

```
print(random_generator())
```